# bootstrap carousel only for mobile devices

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have question about bootstrap4 carousel. I currently have an implemented carousel for all devices, but I want it to appear with only mobile devices. On the desktop, make the photos side by side.
I know I can do two containers one for the desktop and the other one with a carousel. But I would like to avoid it. All proposed solutions are for jQuery, however I am using Angular7 and I would like to avoid jQuery.

```
                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                      <!--  Indicators -->

                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ul>

                            <!--      The slideshow -->

                              <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                  <img src="img1.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                  <img src="img2.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                  <img src="img3.jpg">
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <!-- Left and right controls -->
                              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                                  <mat-icon class="prev-icon">chevron_left</mat-icon>
                                <!--<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>  --> 
                              </a>
                              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                                      <mat-icon class="next-icon">chevron_right</mat-icon>
                              </a>

                            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
img1: string = 'img1.jpg'
img2: string = 'img2.jpg'
img3: string = 'img3.jpg'

isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakPointObserver.observe(['(max-width: 750px)'])
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

  constructor(private breakPointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }
```

template hide on screen less then 750px:

```
<div *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)">
```

Solutions:

```
// this whows on 750-
<div *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async)" id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img [src]="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img [src]="img2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img [src]="img3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <mat-icon class="prev-icon">chevron_left</mat-icon>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <mat-icon class="next-icon">chevron_right</mat-icon>
  </a>
</div>
//this shows on 750+
<div *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)" class="row carousel-inner">
  <div class="col-4 carousel-item">
    <img [src]="img1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 carousel-item">
    <img [src]="img2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 carousel-item">
    <img [src]="img3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The presented solution shows the hidden div below 750px. And the action I want to do is have 3 divs next to each other on the desktop and reduce them to 1 on the mobile and move around them like a carousel in bootstrap.

Comment: `!false = true` or like in `isHandset$= max-width: 750px;` with no "!" bellow 750 is true above false or `!isHandset$` bellow is false above true.

Comment: Even added bootstrap clases so you can coppy paste XD

Comment: Yes, but I still have two divs with the same photos, which I want to avoid

Comment: *ngIf works like if there is false it cut off whole code so user have only one div with same photo. And if u want to get it same on server side u just declare variable like I update in the answer.